# Unable to resolve class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to take use of Pipeline: Groovy Libraries Jenkins plugin, however each time I try to use some classes from the plugin I am getting a following error:

```
15:53:52  [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
15:53:52  ERROR: startup failed:
15:53:52  _48_modeltDevelopJenkinsCasc.groovy: 19: unable to resolve class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries
15:53:52   @ line 19, column 1.
15:53:52     import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries
15:53:52     ^
15:53:52  
15:53:52  _48_modeltDevelopJenkinsCasc.groovy: 20: unable to resolve class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryCachingConfiguration
15:53:52   @ line 20, column 1.
15:53:52     import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryCachingConfiguration
15:53:52     ^
15:53:52  
15:53:52  2 errors
15:53:52  
15:53:52  Finished: FAILURE
```

I have the plugin installed and enabled in the plugins' management section. It is even more confusing to me because if I try to create some plugin class instances in the console like

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.LibraryCachingConfiguration

def test = new LibraryCachingConfiguration(10, "test")
```

then it works

```
Result: LibraryCachingConfiguration{refreshTimeMinutes=10, excludedVersions=test}
```

Executing Jenkins build locally also works fine. Does anyone have any clue what could cause the issue?